# Why logical reads high because of IS NULL in where clause?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

How can I reduce logical reads for the following stored procedure ?

Stored Procedure

```
SELECT 
column1,column2,...
FROM myview as v
WHERE (v.LanguageId IN (1) OR v.LanguageId IS NULL)      
AND OrganisationId IN (1,2,3)  
AND (v.ETypeLanguageId IN (1) OR v.ETypeLanguageId IS NULL)  
AND (v.GTypeLanguageId IN (1) OR v.GTypeLanguageId IS NULL)  
AND v.TargetTypeId IN (2) ORDER BY column1,column2
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

Best Regards,

Comment: may be because of OR ..!!

Comment: You need to examine the statistics and execution plan.  Nobody can tell you from the raw query.  Having said that, consider an index against TargetTypeId and OrganisationID if they will significantly reduce the number of rows to apply the other checks to.

Comment: Are these columns indexed ? ETypeLanguageId, GTypeLanguageId, LanguageId ?

Comment: @g2server, yes those are covering indexes. I would like to add filtered index for those. How can I add ?

Comment: @LoztInSpace, I created the filtered index onTargetTypeId and OrganisationID. They have being used and ok. The problems is because of "OR v.LanguageId IS NULL", "OR v.ETypeLanguageId IS NULL" and "OR v.GTypeLanguageId IS NULL".

Comment: @Lamin. You can't use OR in a filtered index. You can use `IN` though.
However you can't use NULL in the IN clause. You could create a new column that sets NULL = -1 (for example), then you can use the filtered index eg v.ETypeLanguageId IN (1, -1). If that is not acceptable, you could use an indexed view.

Comment: @g2server, I cannot add a new column bcoz this is the existing tables and have a lot of data. I cannot change the table structure. The index view cannot use the left join. The stored procedure joined by left outer joins. :(

Comment: @Lamin. maybe 2 separate filtered indexes, one for the NULL and another for the IN clause ? not sure if the optimizer will make use of it though. Another thing that can help with logical reads is row/page compression.

Comment: @g2server, I tested with 2 separate filtered indexes. They are not being used and the logical read is still high.